# Mixed up Google Accounts with GA Management API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I seem to be having a weird problem with my personal account getting mixed up with my work account when using the GA API... I created a dev con project under my work account and downloaded the client secret json file, but, even though I have never used any Google API with my personal account, the GA API seems to be only picking up my personal site...

Oddly, when I use the Query Explorer, https://go-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer, with the very same work account, I see the correct work GA sites...

I have used the "linked" account before however but I'm quite sure that I was not on my personal account when I created my dev con client secret json Oauth2 stuff...

Has anyone run into this before? How can I unlink my personal account as I need to pull using only my work account?

Thanks for any help you can give...

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check that your home email does not have user access to the work accounts.  It would show up even with only Read access.

Second I'm thinking perhaps you are confusing the Google API console user with the GA authenticated user.

You can create a Google API project with the GA API with your home account, with the OAuth2 and client secret etc.

It is then possible for any user to autheticate with your app (including your work email), it just uses your Google API project to get there.

If you want to keep it all seperate, then try creating the Google API project with your work email instead.

Comment: Well, I don't have any authorized GA projects under my home email. Just a cloud project that was automatically create at some point with no access to any other APIs. Also the client secret is completely different.

I have a separate work account which has everything set up for GA and I have tested it successfully. I used this client secret and it strangely seems to pull my personal site only, which as far as I can tell should be a security violation...

Comment: OK. You were right, I think. The Google API project was set up correctly, but the authenticated user, which I cached awhile ago, must have been my personal one. I nuked the cache and created a new one with the correct account and seems to be fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Google API project was set up correctly, but the authenticated user, which I cached awhile ago, must have been my personal one. I nuked the cache and created a new one with the correct account and seems to be fine.